# PHP datelog localhost on mac permission denied

Tags: php, macos, localhost

I am trying to make a datelog file with PHP. I am running this on xampp on a macbook. It says all the time that permission is denied. How do i fix this?

the error that i am getting is:
Warning: fopen(Friday-01-April-16.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aowigman/index.php on line 6
Unable to open file!

The code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
$datum = date("l-d-F-y");
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

$myfile = fopen("$datum".".txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $datum. " ". $ip."\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you have to change write permission of directory in which you want save the file. Or, if the file already existst, write permission of file.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the permissions as an administrator. Open up terminal on your Mac and then open the directory that file is located in. Then type:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R on directory file located
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Xammp directory, right click and select Read informations. At the bottom of it, click on the chains, enter your password and change permission to read and write to everyone. Now, click on the cog and choose Apply to included elements.

Refresh your page that includes the code, and tadam, fopen(), file_put_contents(), etc, will work.